# Need to write a unit test for service on Jest

Tags: unit-testing, testing, nestjs, typeorm

Help me fix the error, and if possible improve the test itself, because it will be based on further tests for services.

I hope for your help

This is my service file

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { createQueryBuilder, getConnection, getRepository, Repository, getManager, Connection } from 'typeorm';
import { Brands } from './brands/brands.entity';
import { Categories } from './categories/categories.entity';
import { Volumes } from './volumes/volumes.entity';
import { Packages } from './packages/packages.entity';
import { Tags } from './tags/tags.entity';
import { Countries } from './countries/countries.entity';
import { Sub_categories } from './sub_categories/sub_categories.entity';
import { Products } from './products.entity';

import { IProduct } from './products.interface';
import { Collections } from './collections/collections.entity';

@Injectable()
export class ProductsService {

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Products)
    private productRepository: Repository<Products>,
  ) {}

  private readonly products: IProduct[] = [];

    

  async findAllProductsByCategory(category: string): Promise<IProduct[]> {
    const qb = getRepository(Products).createQueryBuilder("products");
    const subQuery: string = qb.subQuery()
      .select('categories.id', 'cat_id')
      .from(Categories, 'categories')
      .where(`cat_id = '${ category }'`)
    .getQuery()

    return await this.findAllProductsByArgument( 'category_id', subQuery );
  }

  async findAllProductsByArgument(argumentId1: string, subQuery1: string, argumentId2?: string, subQuery2?: string): Promise<IProduct[]> {
    const qb = getRepository(Products).createQueryBuilder("products");
    qb
    .select(
      `*, 
      Products.brand_id AS brand_id`
    )
      .addSelect('brands.brand_name', 'brand_name')
      .addSelect('brands.brand_id', 'brand_nameid')
      .addSelect('categories.cat_name', 'cat_name')
      .addSelect('categories.cat_id', 'cat_id')
      .addSelect('volumes.volume_name', 'volume_name')
      .addSelect('volumes.volume_id', 'volume_id')
      .addSelect('tags.name', 'tag_name')
      .addSelect('tags.tag_id', 'tag_nameId')
      .addSelect('sub_categories.subcat_name', 'subcategory_name')
      .addSelect('sub_categories.subcat_id', 'subcategory_id')
      .addSelect('packages.package_name', 'package_name')
      .addSelect('packages.package_id', 'package_nameId')
      .addSelect('countries.country_name', 'country_name')
      .addSelect('countries.country_id', 'country_nameId')
      .addSelect('Products.price', 'price_by_one')
      .innerJoin(Brands, 'brands', 'Products.brand_id = brands.id')
      .innerJoin(Categories, 'categories', 'Products.category_id = categories.id')
      .innerJoin(Volumes, 'volumes', 'Products.volume_id = volumes.id')
      .innerJoin(Tags, 'tags', 'Products.tag_id = tags.id')
      .innerJoin(Sub_categories, 'sub_categories', 'Products.sub_category_id = sub_categories.id')
      .innerJoin(Packages, 'packages', 'Products.package_id = packages.id')
      .innerJoin(Countries, 'countries', 'Products.country_id = countries.id')
      .where('Products.stock > Products.pack_quantity AND isshow = true')
      .andWhere(`Products.${ argumentId1 } = ${ subQuery1 }`);
  
    if(argumentId2 && subQuery2){
      qb.andWhere(`Products.${ argumentId2 } = ${ subQuery2 }`)
    }
  
    return qb.getRawMany();
  }
 }
```

I don't really understand how to mocking data and simulate functions

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

import { Products } from './products.entity';
import { ProductsService } from './products.service';


class ProductsFake {
  public async find(): Promise<void> {}
}


describe('ProductsService', () => {

  let service: ProductsService;
  let repo: Repository<Products>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ProductsService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(Products),
          useClass: ProductsFake
        }
      ]
    }).compile();

    service = module.get(ProductsService);
    repo = module.get(getRepositoryToken(Products));
  });

  describe('finding a products', () => {

    it('should be defined', async () => {
      expect(service).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('return the products list', async () => {

      const product = new Products();
      const mockData = {
        id: 10,
        brand_name: "Brewdog",
        brand_nameid: "brewdog",
        cat_id: "pivo"
      };
      Object.assign(product, mockData);

      const productsRepositoryFindAll = jest
            .spyOn(repo, 'find')
            .mockResolvedValue([product]);

      const result = await service.findAllProductsByCategory( 'pivo' );
      expect(result[0]).toBe(product);
      expect(productsRepositoryFindAll).toBeCalled()
    });

  });

});
```

This is an error that appears when trying to test[image]

Comment: Why are you using `getRepository()` when you already have the `Repository<Products>` class injected?

Comment: @Jay McDoniel, Thank you for your comment, I didn't notice the ad, as a newbie yet. Сould you comment on the test?

Comment: Well, the reason I ask is because `getRepository()` uses the TypeORM `connection` under the hood. In your unit test, a `connection` is never set up (as should be the case for unit tests), so it fails. As you already have a repository injected, I was wondering why you still were trying to get one to make a query builder.